# WorldPop 2020 age structure Jakarta

Tags: google-earth-engine, population

I am trying to download population data for a bunch of world cities using WorldPop/GP/100m/pop_age_sex_cons_unadj data set.

It has has worked for all the cities I'm looking at except Jakarta.

In the `WorldPop/GP/100m/pop_age_sex_cons_unadj` image collection there are 234 images (one for each country) each with 37 bands (1 band that is total population (`population`) and 36 that are age-sex group populations (i.e. `M_25` for males aged 25-29 or `F_80` for females >= 80)

If I map the population band for the Indonesia image, Jakarta has data.

However, when I go to map the age-sex bands nothing appears. I get the same issue when I download each image from WorldPop directly (https://hub.worldpop.org/geodata/summary?id=50343) and upload to gee. There have been papers published that use this age-sex specific data so I know it does exist...I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Code that works:

```
var worldpop2020=ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop_age_sex_cons_unadj");
var totalPop=worldpop2020.select('population');

Map.centerObject(jakarta)
Map.addLayer(totalPop, {
  region: jakarta,
  bands: 'population',
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['24126c', '1fff4f', 'd4ff50']});
```

Code that produces output for rest of Indonesia but not Jakarta

```
var Indonesia=ee.Image('WorldPop/GP/100m/pop_age_sex_cons_unadj/IDN_2020');
var adultpop =Indonesia.select('population').subtract(Indonesia.select('M_0'))
  .subtract(Indonesia.select('M_1')).subtract(Indonesia.select('M_5'))
  .subtract(Indonesia.select('M_10')).subtract(Indonesia.select('M_15'))
  .subtract(Indonesia.select('F_0')).subtract(Indonesia.select('F_1'))
  .subtract(Indonesia.select('F_5')).subtract(Indonesia.select('F_10'))
  .subtract(Indonesia.select('F_15'))
Map.centerObject(jakarta)
Map.addLayer(adultpop, {
  region: jakarta,
  bands: 'population',
  min: 0.0,
  max: 50.0,
  palette: ['24126c', '1fff4f', 'd4ff50']});
```